# how can i fill text into facebook plugin comment by clicking the button using javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview

Is there a method to fill the textfield from a Facebook comment plugin using javascript?

I know how to fill the text into textbox of website using active control by javascript, but it doesn't seem to work on the Facebook comment plugin.

eg. if I click the hello button I want to fill the active textbox text with "hello".

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure that you execute your action **after** the textfield appears in your UIWebView. However, I will highly recommnend making a delegate method instead, detecting the facebook button click, and use the Facebook SDK instead.

Much more freedom instead of having to "hijack" the html and manipulate it after load.

Comment: Hi Nils Munch, 
actually my problem is , i was created my own custom keyboard for uiwebview iphone,
i can fill the textbox of any website using my custom keyboard. (**detect active control and javascript injection**)
but my javascript cannot detect **facebook comment plugin textbox**. So i can't fill the text using my keyboard.